# how does this logic work: num=(rand()%(a+1));

Tags: random

I am finding the answer as to how the line of code prints a random number between 0 and a(both inclusive)

I tried but couldnt understand how this is working.I understand that any big random number is being generated which is then operated with modulus of a+1, which gives me a remainder,but what i cannot grasp is why that should be a number between 0 and a.

Comment: How does this logic work? In general, [poorly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/2166798) if your goal is to get a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rand()` generates a random integer. The range of this random integer depends on the implementation of the `rand()` function in your programming environment. Usually, it generates a random number between 0 and a large maximum value (such as `RAND_MAX` in C/C++).

(a + 1) is added as the right operand of the modulus operator. This means that the random number generated by `rand()` will be divided by (a + 1).

The modulus operation `%` returns the remainder of dividing the random number by (a + 1).

I guess this part is most significant for answering your question. **Since the divisor is (a + 1), the possible remainders will be between 0 and a inclusive** since possible remainders when dividing some number N are all numbers between 0 and (N - 1) including both boundaries.

For example, let's say a = 5. If the random number generated by `rand()` is 12, then (12 % 6) would be 0, because 12 is evenly divisible by 6. If the random number is 15, then (15 % 6) would be 3, because 15 divided by 6 gives a quotient of 2 with a remainder of 3. Thus, the result stored in num will always be a number between 0 and a.